# Polymer data binding: use property in path?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Is it possible to use a property in the path (marked PROPERTY below)?

```
<template is="dom-if" if="[[one.two.PROPERTY.four]]">
 ...
</template>

class MyTag extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() {return 'my-tag'}
  static get properties() {
    return {
      PROPERTY: String
    }
  }
}
customElements.define(MyTag.is, MyTag)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<dom-module id="my-tag">
  <template>
    <template is="dom-if" if="{{_ifFour}}">
      <b>yo</b>
    </template>
  </template>

  <script>
  class TestElement extends Polymer.Element {

    static get is() { return 'my-tag' }

    static get properties () {
      return {
        PROPERTY: {
          type: String,
          value: 'initial',
          observer: '_PROPERTYChanged'
        },

        one: {
          type: Object,
          value: function () {
            return {
              two: {}
            }
          }
        },

        _ifFour: {
          type: Boolean,
          value: false
        }
      }
    }

    static get observers () {
      return ['_computeIfFour(one.*)']
    }

    _computeIfFour () {
      if (this.one.two[this.PROPERTY] === undefined)
        this._ifFour = false;

      this._ifFour = this.one.two[this.PROPERTY].four;
    }

    _PROPERTYChanged (propertyName, old) {
      if (old) {
        delete this.one.two[old];
      }
      this.one.two[propertyName] = {
        four: ''
      }
    }

  }

  customElements.define(MyTag.is, MyTag)
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

there is actually a way that's working. but this is too much *hacky* you shouldn't use that in a production code. if that's shared it is gross and if your code is likely to grow, you'll probably have undesired side-effects to it.

Comment: Here's what I want to do `<my-tag property="foo">` and `<my-tag property="bar">`. Now inside the template that will become `one.two.foo.four`  for the first and `one.two.bar.four` for the second.

Comment: @Sunny I think you shouldn't go so wild, believe me Polymer is a very tight framework but when you try to start to make your own rules it will occasionally start to not respond the way you'd expect.

Comment: I've taken your advice and settled for a more basic/redundant approach, as there doesn't seem to be a simple way to create dynamic paths. Thanks!